# Show different first active Bootstrap tab-pane depending on the resolution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Is there any way to start with one active `tab-pane` for desktop resolutions but with different one for everything lower than `992px` (mobile)?

So I have something like:

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_1">
    something
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
    something else
</div>
```

Now I'd rather have the classes `.in` and `.active` in tab_2 instead of tab_1 when the resolution is lower than `992px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.

By operating the DOM, CSS classes are editable. In your case, as long as the window size can be detected dynamically, the `.fade` and `.in` classes will be placed as expected.

Here is the code snippet by using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function changeTab() {
        if ($(window).width()< 992) {
            $("#tab_1").removeClass("fade in");
            $("#tab_2").addClass("fade in");
        }else{
            $("#tab_1").addClass("fade in");
            $("#tab_2").removeClass("fade in");
        }
    }
    changeTab();

    // Bind the function, it will be executed once window is resized.
    $(window).resize(changeTab);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single tab-pane which was used for all resolutions, but have the content of that pane be dependent on the resolution, so only the correct one showed.

(Not sure if I interpreted your question properly...)

Comment: Thanks but I need to have the content in different tab-panes with different tabs on top.
I guess I need some "JS magic" that checks what Bootstrap resolution I´m currently in and puts the .active class accordingly?